# Why there is construction when reducing a vector's size?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, stdvector

I'm confusing about what exactly does `vector::resize()` do when reducing  elements. 
My experiment codes are as following (without headers), under c++03:

```cpp
struct Bar {
    Bar() { cout << "C" << endl; }
    Bar(const Bar& other) { cout << "P" << endl; }
    ~Bar() { cout << "D" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    vector<Bar> v(5);
    cout << "resize to 2" << endl;
    v.resize(2);
    cout << "clear" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
C
P
P
P
P
P
D
resize to 2
C  <- why here is a Construction?
D
D
D
D  <- the corresponding Destruction?
clear
D
D
```

As the output shows, it first create a temporary object and makes 5 copies. Then when I resize it to 2, there appears a construction! What's the construction for? I thought there should be only 3 destructions.

Comment: The question you point is about increasing the size which I understand. I think it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Read the first answer, it absolutely answers your question, before C++11 `resize` is defined as `void resize( size_type count, T value = T() );`, that's where the extra copy comes in. The constructor's the same.

Comment: Aha, I just see that. Thanks. :) This question is ready for close.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, as that one doesn't cover the case of resizing the vector to be smaller. Close enough I suppose

Comment: Note that since C++11 the constructor is not allowed to do one construction then 5 copy-constructions as your code did. It must default-construct each object.